# R - finding pattern in a column and replacing it (more efficient solution)

Tags: r, substring, sapply

I have a large data set of passengers per route similar to the following:

```
routes <- c("MEX-GDL", "ACA-MEX", "CUN-MTY", "MTY-CUN", "GDL-MEX", "MEX-ACA")
pax <- sample(100:500, size = 6, replace = T)
traffic <- data.frame(routes = routes, pax = pax)

   routes pax
   1 MEX-GDL 282
   2 ACA-MEX 428
   3 CUN-MTY 350
   4 MTY-CUN 412
   5 GDL-MEX 474
   6 MEX-ACA 263
```

I want to group flights if the origin and destination match as to get the total number of passengers in the route - so for example renaming the route `MEX-GDL` as `GDL-MEX` or viceversa so I can then use `group_by()` on the data set.

Kind of like this:

```
traffic %>% group_by(routes) %>% summarise(sum(pax))
```

I have done the following and it works, but I believe there can be a more efficient way to solve the problem (as it takes quite some time to run):

```
library(tidyverse)

traffic$routes <- as.character(traffic$routes)

for(route in traffic$routes){
  a <- substring(route, first = 1, last = 3) 
  b <- substring(route, first = 5, last = 7)
  aux <- which(sapply(traffic$routes, str_detect, pattern = paste0(b,"-",a)))
  traffic$routes[aux] <- paste0(a,"-",b)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

**Note:** it's my first question here, so I hope I complied with all the guidelines.

Comment: Great first question! If only all the new users could do this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can `separate` into two columns, grouped by the `pmax` or `pmin`, get the `sum`

```
library(tidyverse)
traffic %>% 
   separate(routes, into = c("Col1", "Col2")) %>%
   group_by(ColN = pmin(Col1, Col2), ColN2 = pmax(Col1, Col2)) %>% 
   summarise(Sum = sum(pax))
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` version

data: (`?I` [READ THIS](https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/))

```
traffic <- data.frame(routes = I(routes), pax = pax)

library(data.table)
setDT(traffic)[,routes := sapply(strsplit(routes, split="-"), function(x) paste0(sort(x),collapse = "-"))][,.(Sum = sum(pax)), by = routes]
```

result: (values differ because of `sample` function)

```
#    routes Sum
#1: GDL-MEX 621
#2: ACA-MEX 595
#3: CUN-MTY 266
```

---

- If you use data with `?sample` use `?set.seed` along with it.